# Why would this wordpress site be redirecting

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Ok so i have this [wp site](http://dev.petmate.com/) and for some reason it always redirects to a page i just created. The page i just created was named (our other brands)...I even tried deleting the page and the file that i create page-our-other-brands.php but the redirect is still there. I looked in the htaccess and nothing and i have no idea what is causing this redirect ...any ideas

Comment: What urls did you enter in Admin/Settings/General? Do you have an .htaccess redirect in your public_html folder? are you using redirection plugin?

Comment: fyi its not a meta refresh or htaccess it a header one header('Refresh: 0; url=./about-petmate/our-other-brands'); then  ./about-petmate/our-other-brands is again redirecting too /our-other-brands

Comment: how did you find that one header('Refresh: 0; url=./about-petmate/our-other-brands') ....is there a way to find see this myself...the page refreshes to the new location before i can see anything

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin site there is a link for configuration/setting go there

and there is an option to set the home page for wordpress site change it.

Go to Administration > Settings > Reading panel and change it.

Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

Comment: if you mean the WordPress address (URL) then that is already set to dev.petmate.com

Comment: @Tamer:No you also can select the landing page set it to home